# Not able to run a test in Karate using maven command

Tags: maven, karate

Getting error as [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project KarateUdemy: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) and my feature file is

Feature: sample karate api test script

Background:
* url 'URL'

Scenario: Login into application
Given path '/api/authentication/login'
And request {"userName": "username","password": "password"},
When method post
Then status 200
And print response
And match response.status == "Authorized"
* def Authtoken = response.token

Comment: works for me. please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue